# error installing dplyr library in R 3.4.1

Tags: r, linux, installation, dplyr

I'm trying to install dplyr package (0.7.x version) and I get multiples error during the compilation.

make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo `rlang-export.c', necesario para`rlang-export.o'.  Alto.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’

Does anybody help me?

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Thanks

Comment: It happened to me once a few months ago. It did not work on a  fresh installation of lubuntu in french (16.04), albeit it did in a similar install of ubuntu in english. I fixed it with  this solution: https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/194 , i.e. running first install.packages("rlang", type = "source") and then installing tidy verse, which includes dplyr.

Comment: Thanks for your  help. I have followed your notes but now I get other new error:   make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo `hybrid_minmax.cpp', necesario para `hybrid_minmax.o'.  Alto.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/s9169/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dplyr’
* restoring previous ‘/home/rstudio/s9169/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dplyr’

Comment: ¿Estas corriendo R como sudo? Tal vez eso ayude.

Comment: Yes, I am running R as sudo.